# Is it possible to have Item and Document content type in same list or library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

Possible to have document and item content type in same list or library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible - document library allows only document related Content Types. In case of Custom List, you will find **Document Set** on a list of available content types, which may indicate that storing documents within custom list is possible, but when you try to add this content type, you will receive an error.

Only option (which may match your requirements) is to add Document Set content type to a document library and add required fields to it. This way you will have documents and item alike entries. But basically document sets are not meant for that.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I know above points but i am just curious about to know is there any limitation or specific reason on msdn?

Comment: It may be related with different display templates and options which are available for documents and are not available for items. Also versioning works differently for items and documents.

Comment: Answering your question - I did not found anything on MSDN, presented conclusions base on my experience only, but I do not have any 'hard evidence' for that:)

Comment: Even i don't find anything related to this topic that's why i am putting this here.

Comment: I get your point - in this case I can only hope that somebody else will know and share it with us:)